# Find Difference from Previous Consecutive Row in Google Query Pivot Table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, pivot-table

Say I have source data like the below:
`OriginDate|Name|IncidentDate|` where `Origin Date` is constant and the earliest date of my imported data set.  I've formatted the dates to numbers so I can perform calculations in query.

```
    AO       X         AP
OriginDate|Name|IncidentDate
5/19/2019 |Mary|5/21/2019
5/19/2019 |Lisa|5/29/2019
5/19/2019 |Lisa|5/29/2019
5/19/2019 |Lisa|6/1/2019
```

[image]

I've successfully created a google query pivot to get to the following:

`=query('Source Data'!A1:AU,"SELECT AP,((SUM(AP)/COUNT(AP))-AO) group by AO, AP pivot X label ((SUM(AP)/COUNT(AP))-AO) ' ' ")`

```
           Lisa    Mary
6/1/2019    13
5/29/2019   10
5/21/2019            2
```

[image]

What I'm trying to result is the calculated difference between Lisa's incidents on 6/1 and 5/29 or 3 days to know Lisa went 3 days between errors.  The reason I'm dividing by count AP is that a pivot table adds dates together if there are multiple errors on the same day. I use the minimum date of the source data as the baseline on the sheet.  That's the Origin Date value.  I'm not sure it's needed but I could at least perform that subtraction and it worked.

My data is constantly updating so I'm using `Importrange` to get the data daily thus the need for a query.

Anyone got any clever ideas on how to get to this final step?  I tried in excel to use diff from previous in a pivot table but could not get that to work either.